# webservice timeout c#

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a c# application and I want to fire off a webservice but I dont care about the response and I also dont care if it fails. At the moment i fire of the service async but i am getting an error when the call fails.

Is there anyway I can configure the app/webservice to stop it failing without rapping try catches around them (basiclly fire and forget)?

Thanks
Sp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one idea:

Write your web service do that it returns 'success' right away, then fires off an async process that does the work.

You can also do this by creating a queue or something, where another process watches the queue and performs the work.  Then the web service's only job, then, is to add an entry to the queue.